# On mouse hover the <a> tag underline transition from left to right and on mouse out the underline transition is back right to left

Tags: html, css

Right now whenever you hover one of the `<a>` elements a div transitions from left to right under the hovered element, however, when I stop hovering it disappears instantly instead of hovering back. How can I make it so it hovers back to it's original position?

What I have so far is this:

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.links {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
}
.links a {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0px 30px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    position: relative;
}
.links a:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 4px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 25px;
    right: 0;
    background: #fff;
    transition: width .2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: width .3s ease;
}
.links a:hover:after{
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
        <div class='links'>
            <a href=''>
                <p>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</p>
            </a>
            <a href=''>
                <p>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</p>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <p>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</p>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: remove right:0 and keep only left:0 on the non-hover state

Comment: So remove right: 0 and add left: 0 to .links a:after ? Not sure if that's what I was meant to do but it didn't change a thing.

Comment: remove the left:0 from the hover and keep only the right:0 where it is .. then if you want to change simply change right to left, you shouldn't have them on hover

Comment: don't forget that you are changing the background from white to another color

Comment: But now it appears from right to left on hover and that's not what I'm trying to achieve. I want it to go from left to right on hover like it does now AND then to go back from right to left when I stop hovering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution, try this.

```css
.footer_menu {
  padding: 30px 0 0;
}
.footer_menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.footer_menu ul.bottom-menu {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.footer_menu ul li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
.footer_menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666666;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.footer_menu ul li a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.footer_menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}
.footer_menu ul li a:hover::before {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer_menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">test test</a></li>
<li><a href="#">test test</a></li>
</ul>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cas use `ease-in` by default and on `:hover` `ease-out`